# «Хочу стать как Лермонтов» - нужна ли запятая перед «как»?

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед «как» в предложении «Хочу стать как Лермонтов»?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря в каком смысле "стать", в прямом (занять позицию) или в переносном (стать таким - в этом случае запятая не нужна). Если в прямом:

> Хочу стать, как Лермонтов перед Мартыновым, и ждать выстрела.

(ср. *Стань передо мной, как лист перед травой!*)

Comment: У, змий коварррный... Нам же дадено законченное предложение.

Comment: В нём точки не было :)

Comment: Сашко, у нас там Мета оживлённую жизнь повела - заходь глянуть! Я аж три вопроса сумела сформулировать. Пабаисси атветить? https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/users/177616/galina-avanesova

Answer (score 0):

Да ни за что - лучше сразу застрелиться.

Перед нами неделимое сказуемое - и никаких сравнений.

См. [Сравнительные обороты и обороты с КАК](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/725-29_sravnitelnye_oboroty_i_oboroty_s_kak.html).

---

> [Вопрос № 291708](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=291708)
>
> Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед КАК: *Хочу
>   быть как...*
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Если за союзом следует слово (как все, как Амундсен), запятая не
>   нужна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]